# TypeScript: how do I type-annotate an object with attributes all of the same type? (Object<type> Array<type>)

Tags: typescript, object, types, enums

I want to strongly-type my `festivals` object using TypeScript types. Each attribute is always of the type `IFestival`. I don't want to have to define `IFestivals` in the way that I have, as there are about 20 more attributes. Is there a way I can tell TypeScript that every attribute associated with an object will be of the same type? A bit like how you could do `type IFestivals = Array<IFestival>` but `IFestivals = Object<IFestival>` instead?

Code below:

```js
interface IFestival {
  name: string;
  festival?: boolean;
  favourite?: boolean;
}

// I do not want to define it this way as there are 25+ attributes like this in reality...
interface IFestivals extends Object {
  BESTIVAL: IFestival;
  GLASTONBURY: IFestival;
  LOVEBOX: IFestival;
  MIGHTY_HOOPLA: IFestival;
  PARKLIFE: IFestival;
}

const festivals: IFestivals = {
  BESTIVAL: { name: "Bestival", festival: true },
  GLASTONBURY: { name: "Glastonbury", festival: true, favourite: true },
  LOVEBOX: { name: "Lovebox", festival: true },
  MIGHTY_HOOPLA: { name: "Mighty Hoopla", festival: true },
  PARKLIFE: { name: "Parklife", festival: true }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use an [indexed type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) (or a `Map<string,IFestival>`), which doesn't control the names of the properties (you can only index by `string | number` or `number`, not an enum or similar):

```
type IFestivals = {[name: string]: IFestival};
```

...then you're going to be writing *something* 25 times. That's really not that big a deal.

Your best bet is to do what you've done, although without the `extends Object` which is implicit:

```
interface IFestivals {
  BESTIVAL: IFestival;
  GLASTONBURY: IFestival;
  LOVEBOX: IFestival;
  MIGHTY_HOOPLA: IFestival;
  PARKLIFE: IFestival;
  // ...
}
```

But if you were going to need to have those 25 properties with one type in one interface and another type in another interface, you could use a generic:

```
interface Samey<T> {
  BESTIVAL: T;
  GLASTONBURY: T;
  LOVEBOX: T;
  MIGHTY_HOOPLA: T;
  PARKLIFE: T;
  // ...
}
type IFestivals = Samey<IFestival>;
type ISomethingElses = Samey<ISomethingElse>;
```

There's no reason to do that for a single interface, though.